# Is there any way to intercept reloading event for Android?

Tags: react-native

When I am running my application on Android device (virtual device) It connects using WebSocket. It's normal flow and there is no question here. When I am using the virtual device for developing I use "Reload" all the time (sure). Can I intercept the reloading process for disconnecting the WS connect? If I do not it manually that my backend won't get relevant event.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to emit the disconnect message in the componentWillUnmount() function. It is bad to use it in a normal app flow (in a back button for example) as it is normally an async function and it is not a good approach to call async functions in the componentWillUnmount(), but in cases that you will only handle the "quit" (reload in your case) I think that this solution can help.

Comment: It doesn't work 'cos the reloading flow doesn't include destroying flow of application